# SAS appending 2 datasets with different variables

Tags: merge, sas

I have the 2 datasets below:

Table A:

```
ID  COL1 COL2
1   X     X
2   X     Y
3   Z     Z
```

TABLE B:

```
ID  COL1 COL3
1   X     X
4   X     Y
5   Z     Z
```

The result I'm expecting:

```
   ID    COL1 COL2 COL3
        1   X     X
        2   X     Y
        3   Z     Z
        4   X         y
        5   z         z
```

But when using the macro below, the COL3 gets truncated.

```
%macro append(dsn);
proc append base=tablea data=&dsn;
run;
%mend append;

%append(tableb);
```

Answer (score 1):

`PROC APPEND` has different rules than the result you would get with just using a `SET` statement.  One of those rules is that it does not modify the BASE dataset. So it cannot add the new variable.  Sounds like you want this instead.

```
data tablea ;
  set tablea tableb;
run;
```

Comment: I thought about a SET statement as well but both are very large datasets and the query would take too long

Comment: I believe there are other options (always are!). But if your DS's are sorted, as they are above, believe a simple `merge` by `ID` would accomplish what you asking for as well. Then you'll create your missing values in column 3, for ID values of 4 and 5. Cannot comment on speed however, since I do not know how big your tables are.

Comment: Since you are modifying the definition of TABLEA by adding a column there is no way to avoid having to re-write the data.